# linkbutton inside update panel not working

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, asplinkbutton

The page has table inside updatePanel and linkbutton inside tablecell:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" 
        BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Both" BorderStyle="Solid">
    </asp:Table>
  </ContentTemplate>        
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Inside .cs file I add rows to the table:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.Text = "Click me";
lb.Click += new EventHandler(this.LinkButton_Click);
tc.Controls.Add(lb);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
```

And the method:

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
  Response.Write("alert('Ok!');");
  Response.Write("</script>");  
}
```

So, when I click linkbutton the alert doesn't work.
What is a problem?

Note that, if I delete updatepanel the linkbutton works when clicking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the correct way

Use this

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pnlUpdateCom, this.GetType(), "UpdateCom", "alert('OK!.');return false;", true);

Comment: The function not only uset for alerting messages, but also has another functions..

Comment: You can write any javascript code inside it.

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pnlUpdateCom, this.GetType(), "UpdateCom", "javascript code", true);

You can any javascript function

Comment: One question. Is it possible to work with server control, for example with asp.net table inside javascript function? For instance, I want to add new rows to asp.net table using variables inside .cs file?

Comment: Your question is not clear!
You want to add rows to asp.net table using javascript i.e. from client side or in .cs file.
Using server side its easy and I expect you have the idea.
Using javascript first try implementing using javascript function from aspx page and when you are getting the required output just call that function using RegisterStartupScript.

Comment: I fill asp.net table in C#, i.e. TableRow tr = new TableRow(); TableCell tc = new TableCell(); tc.Text = myarray[i]; tr.controls.add(tc); table1.rows.add(tr); So, is it possible to implement this code using javascript function?

Comment: Frankly speaking I have not tried this yet as I have not got a chance for such implementation. I believe it can be done in Javascript but you might face issues while reading the same from Table on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add postbacktrigger as following:

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="SearchBrn"/>
```